# values are not shown up when using the second for loop - Python

Tags: python, arrays, json, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm was trying to do random selection in the data, but I was stuck when using for-loop to nest all data into an array.

**Data**

```
data = [
    {"Animal1": "Dog", "Animal2": "Cat", "Animal3": "Snake"},
    {"Animal1": "Mouse", "Animal2": "Ant", "Animal3": "Chicken"},
    {"Animal1": "Fish", "Animal2": "Elephant", "Animal3": "Fox"},
    {"Animal1": "rabbit", "Animal2": "sheep", "Animal3": "wolf"}
]
```

**My code:**

```
new_data = []

for rows in data:
    for row in rows:
        new_data.append(row)

print(new_data)
```

**Output**

```
['Animal1', 'Animal2', 'Animal3', 'Animal1', 'Animal2', 'Animal3', 'Animal1', 'Animal2', 'Animal3', 'Animal1', 'Animal2', 'Animal3']
```

**Expected output**

```
{
    "Animal1": "Dog", "Animal2": "Cat", "Animal3": "Snake",
    "Animal1": "Mouse", "Animal2": "Ant", "Animal3": "Chicken",
    "Animal1": "Fish", "Animal2": "Elephant", "Animal3": "Fox",
    "Animal1": "rabbit", "Animal2": "sheep", "Animal3": "wolf"
}
```

Comment: Your expected output is not valid Python

Comment: I just edited the expected output.

Comment: Your expected output is impossible, because a `dict` cannot have multiple instances of the same key (e.g. `"Animal1"` is used four times)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like:

```
from collections import defaultdict

results = defaultdict(list)

for rows in data:
    for key, value in rows.items():
        results[key].append(value)
```